# bootstrap, the else part of javascript doesn't display correct results

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing form validation with [javascript](https://pastebin.com/6eLxF9FC) the last if statement is suppose to print out the error, it check for an empty variable and displays the result. The first part works as it should, but the `else` part displays [red box instead of green](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-control-validation)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Assignment 2</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->

    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var confirm = document.getElementById("confirm").value;
            var age =  document.getElementById("age").value;
            var error = " ";

            //Checking for blank fields.
            if(name == ""){
                document.getElementById("name_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                error += "Please Enter Your Name. " + "<br />";
            }
            else{
                //Checking for Username containing only a-z (uppercase or lowercase)
                if(!name.match(/[a-z]/i)){ //name.match() checks variable against regular expression
                    document.getElementById("name_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                    error += "Username must contain only alphabetical characters. " + "<br />";
                }
                else{
                    //Checking Username length.
                    if(name.length<5 || name.length>15){
                        document.getElementById("name_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                        error+="Required length is 5-15 characters. " + "<br />";
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("name_form").className = "form-group has-success";
                    }
                }
            }
            if(password == ""){
                document.getElementById("password_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                error += "Enter a Password. " + "<br />";
            }
            /*else{
                document.getElementById("password_form").className = "form-group has-success";
            }*/
            if(confirm == ""){
                document.getElementById("confirm_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                error += "Confirm Password. " + "<br />";
            }
            else{
                //Checking Password and Confirm
                if(password != confirm){
                    document.getElementById("password_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                    document.getElementById("confirm_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                    error += "Passwords don't match. " + "<br />";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("password_form").className = "form-group has-success";
                    document.getElementById("confirm_form").className = "form-group has-success";
                }
            }
            if(age == ""){
                document.getElementById("age_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                error += "Enter Age. " + "<br />";
            }
            else{
                //Checking Age for -ve #s
                if(age < 0){
                   document.getElementById("age_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                   error += "Age can't be negative." + "<br />";
                }
                else{
                    //Checking Age range
                    if(age < 18 || age > 110){
                        document.getElementById("age_form").className = "form-group has-error";
                        error += "Age is out of range. " + "<br />";
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("age_form").className = "form-group has-success";
                    }
                }
            }

            //Printing the errors
            if(error){
                document.getElementById("errors").className = "alert alert-danger";
                document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = error;
            }
            else{
            //if(error == null){
                document.getElementById("errors").className = "alert alert-success";
                document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "Form Values Successfully Validated";
            }

            //Debugging
            console.log(error);
            //return error;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <div class="form-group" id="name_form">
        <label for="name">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="password_form">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="confirm_form">
        <label for="confirm">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="age_form">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age">
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>

    <!--Resets the page-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.reload()">Reset</button>
</form> <br /><br />

<div id="errors">

</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your full code here

Comment: you initialize error to a string with spaces.  var error = "  ", so it will never go into the else portion of the statement

Comment: Another minor issue, how can I restrict username to just letters, right now I have ```if(!name.match(/[a-z]/i))``` , but it accepts numbers.

Comment: you are miss using the match statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/match-method-string-javascript

Comment: @Bindrid Sorry would you mind explaining what am I doing wrong. I've made a variable ``` var invalidChars = /[^0-9]/gi``` and changed my if statement to ```if(name.match(/[a-z]/i) === invalidChars)``` comparing one to another, but there's no effect.

Comment: "some string".match(/[^a-z]/i)  would work. It will look for anything but a-z (case insensitive) so if it returns null, your good to go. If it returns an array, you have illegal characters